# Is there any way to show the entirety of our Chatter Feed on a VF page?

Tags: visualforce

I'd like to create a VF page that shows every Chatter post.

The VF Page I created was pretty simple, but it only shows my posts, any ideas?

didn't seem to work..

Comment: Without pagination or infinite scrolling or something, this would start to get pretty unusable pretty quickly.